# How do I use a layout xml file in a tab under the standard swipe+tab model

Tags: android, tabs, swipe

I created a project using Eclipse Juno with ADT selecting the swipe+tab model for ICS version. I see in the generated code that there is a section that creates a textview and places the page/tab number in the center of the textview presented at runtime.

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Create a new TextView and set its text to the fragment's section
        // number argument value.
        TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        textView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return textView;
```

However, instead of presenting a textview on each tab, I would like to present an XML file from my Layouts... a unique layout for each tab. I think I need to use something like this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.tab1);
```

OR

```
setContentView(R.layout.tab2);
```

But I cannot seem to figure out how to get this to work in my tabs. Advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out how to present my XML Layout file (main.xml) in one of the tabs by using this code:

```
    public DummySectionFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Create a new TextView and set its text to the fragment's section
        // number argument value.

        if ((getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)==1)) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
            return view; 
            }
            else {
                TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
                textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                textView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
                return textView;
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps you too!

Comment: Could you share some more code? I am trying to do what you explained in your question, but have no idea how the answer works. Especially the `DummySectionFragment`?

Comment: Hi JuiCe, I would be happy to try to help but believe I have already shared the complete code relevant to the issue above. Please study the example provided in the solution and post your specific questions so the community can try to help you further. I think the key point is that I am checking to see when ARG_SECTION_NUMBER is 1 to show my XML Layout called main (R.layout.main) otherwise I use the default code provided by the wizard to show the tab number.